# Any way to add block on only enterprise editions?

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-enterprise

I understand how to add blocks via layout xml. But i have a situation where i want to add a few of these blocks on only enterprise edition. On other edition it should work as if that block has not even been added in the xml.

I know that there is an attribute called `ifconfig` but is it reliable for determining the enterprise edition? If so, what could be the configuration node i could check?

Another way for achieving the above, i was thinking of listening to an appropriate event & add a new layout handle (or maybe a new layout xml file?) for enterprise editions & add my new blocks in that. Am i doing it right or is there any better/easier way?

Also i would prefer if i do not have to do it via php code as that code will get very lengthy with the number of blocks & also because all the blocks that are added on community edition are being added via xml

Comment: Did you try `ifconfig="modules/Enterprise_Enterprise/active"`?

Comment: Yes, but not working. I think it only supports fields from under system config

Comment: What about `ifconfig="system/media_storage_configuration/allowed_resources/enterprise_folder"`? I know, it doesn't look clean but better than with php code.

Comment: Perfect. Can you please put that as an answer? One thing i would like to note though is that default magento doesn't support `ifconfig` on `block` tag, it only accepts on `action` tag. So if your block has `type` as one of the Enterprise classes, you should still go for php code

Comment: For my solution though, i ended up dynamically adding a new enterprise-only xml file.

Comment: If you unaccept because you accomplished another way, you should post your own answer.

Comment: Posted my comment as answer, plus solution how to make `ifconfig` attribute work on `block` tag. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `ifconfig="system/media_storage_configuration/allowed_resources/enterprise_folde‌​r"`? I know, it doesn't look clean but better than with php code.

P.S. To make `ifconfig` attribute work on `block` tag you should install
[Aoe_LayoutConditions](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-layout-xml-conditions.html) module.

Answer (score 5):

**Don't use layout XML**

Rather than using layout XML, perhaps add the block in the parent block programmatically from within your conroller, using `Mage::getEdition()`, which has been available since 1.12 EE.

It would look something like this:

```
if(Mage::getEdition()=='Enterprise'){


    $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('core/template')
        ->setTemplate('myfolder/myfile.phtml');

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

}
```

Possible values for Magento's Edition constants are:

```
const EDITION_COMMUNITY    = 'Community';
const EDITION_ENTERPRISE   = 'Enterprise';
const EDITION_PROFESSIONAL = 'Professional';
const EDITION_GO           = 'Go';
```

**I don't care, I want Layout XML**

You can use `ifconfig`, but your installer will have to create a config entry for the edition in a startup script. That will have to return a 'true' value (1); let's call that config node `system/magento/enterprise_edition`:

```
<block ifconfig="system/magento/enterprise_edition" type="enterprise_customerbalance/checkout_onepage_payment_additional" .../>
```

**I need support for < 1.12**

As stated, `Mage::getEdition()` won't work for < 1.12; The layout XML example would work, but you'd have to sniff which version for your installer. SweetToothRewards does this by checking the presence of a module:

```
/**
 * True if the version of Magento currently being run is Enterprise Edition
 */
public function isMageEnterprise() {
    return Mage::getConfig ()->getModuleConfig ( 'Enterprise_Enterprise' ) && Mage::getConfig ()->getModuleConfig ( 'Enterprise_AdminGws' ) && Mage::getConfig ()->getModuleConfig ( 'Enterprise_Checkout' ) && Mage::getConfig ()->getModuleConfig ( 'Enterprise_Customer' );
}


public function isMageProfessional() {
    return Mage::getConfig ()->getModuleConfig ( 'Enterprise_Enterprise' ) && !Mage::getConfig ()->getModuleConfig ( 'Enterprise_AdminGws' ) && !Mage::getConfig ()->getModuleConfig ( 'Enterprise_Checkout' ) && !Mage::getConfig ()->getModuleConfig ( 'Enterprise_Customer' );
}


public function isMageCommunity() {
    return !$this->isMageEnterprise() && !$this->isMageProfessional();
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/jayelkaake

Comment: +1 for the useful information. However, i prefer doing it via xml only. The reason is that all the other blocks(that are added irrespective of edition) are all added via xml. This makes things more consistent.

Comment: See my most recent update.

Answer (score 0):

instead of determining versions determine the feature. If you add this with layout file then place the layout file that has this rule to `app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/layout` folder and it will be included only for enterprise installations.

Comment: but how to determine the feature? In one of the block, i have to show it if store credit feature is available, i have `<block type="enterprise_customerbalance/checkout_onepage_payment_additional" .../>`. However this throws an exception on community edition.

Comment: add the block via xml and inside this block check if store_credit module is present and if it is enabled

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean here, can you give me an example? Take the xml mentioned in previous comment for an example.